# How to create a glib.Source from Python?

Tags: python, pygtk, glib, asyncore

I want to integrate some [`asyncore.dispatcher`](http://file:///usr/share/doc/python-doc/html/library/asyncore.html#asyncore.dispatcher) instances into GLib's [default main context](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-context-default).

I figure I can create a [custom `GSource`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-new) that's able to detect event readiness on the various sockets in [`asyncore.socket_map`](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/asyncore.py). From C I believe this is done by creating the necessary [`GSourceFuncs`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSourceFuncs) which could involve cheap and non-blocking calls to select, and then handling them using asyncore.read, .write and friends.

How do I actually create a GSource from Python? The class glib.Source is [undocumented](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/2.26/), and attempts to use the class interactively have been in vain.

Is there some other method that allows me to handled socket events in the [`asyncore`](http://file:///usr/share/doc/python-doc/html/library/asyncore.html) module without resorting to timeouts (or anything that endangers potential throughput and CPU usage)?

Answer (score 0):

glib.io_add_watch does it (add a watch over a fd to the main loop):

http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/2.26/glib-functions.html#function-glib--io-add-watch

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to integrate a dispatcher with a glib loop is shown, very simplified, below:

```
from asyncore import dispatcher, loop
from glib import MainLoop, idle_add

def loop_one():
    loop(timeout=0, count=1)
    return True

idle_add(loop_one)
```

Comment: From my question: _without resorting to timeouts (or anything that endangers potential throughput and CPU usage)_. You may remove the answer.

Comment: Since the timeout is zero it will not really use a timeout, the function will return directly (actually as soon as it's done processing the data, but it will never wait on io) wherever there where any data to read or not.

Comment: This function will be called whenever there are no higher priority events pending to the default main loop so yes it will suck CPU for no reason. There is no point in using an event loop if you can't actually use events !